# Sending JSON to IIS from iPhone in hebrew the string cut before the end

Tags: iphone, json, http, post, sbjson

Im sending data to a server from my iPhone app, with this code:

```
- (void) sendGeneral:(NSString *) general{
    self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:CBURL]];  
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    sendString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:general];

    requestData = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:[sendString UTF8String] length:[sendString length]];
    [request setHTTPBody:requestData];

    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

As long as I send latin in the data it all sent well and the server getting the full string
when I'm sending hebrew data in it it is cut some where and the server dosent get all data, on Xcode debug I can see the full string as I use `NSLog` to output it:

> {"Session":{"customer_id":-1,"client_time":"3","user_id":-1,"device_token":"3"},"Error":{"error_code":-1,"error_message":"3"},"Successful":{"success_code":-1,"success_message":"3"},"Details":{"StartCallID":-1,"user_password":"כ","user_name":"ככ","StartDate":"3","EndDate":"3"},"Ptype":{"Ptype":3}}

can some one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure this will fix your problem, is hebrew UTF8 or UTF16?? My guess is you're getting cut off about halfway through the data? That would imply that sendString length returns only half the number of bytes if it's UTF16.

A better way to do this would be as such:

```
[request setHTTPBody:[general dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
// or if it's UTF16 
[request setHTTPBody:[general dataUsingEncoding: NSUnicodeStringEncoding]];
```

Comment: Thanks Byron, this solve my problem, but still i see the hebrew data like this "???????????" on my server any idea?

Comment: which version fixed it? The NSUnicodeStringEncoding? If so your server might have the same problem, it thinks it's ascii or utf8. What platform are you running your server on?